# Issue with hanging vagrant up on win7 while configuring network adapter

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

Vagrant version: 1.4.0
vagrant-windows version: 1.5.1

Vagrant file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config| 
  config.vm.box = "win7.x86.v.004"
  config.vm.box_url = "URL"
  config.vm.boot_timeout = 300
  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
  end
  config.windows.halt_timeout = 15
  config.winrm.username = "vagrant"
  config.winrm.password = "vagrant"
  config.vm.guest = :windows
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5985, host: 5685, id: "winrm", :auto => true
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 5986, host: 5686
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 8080, host: 5687
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 1521, host: 5688
  config.winrm.host = "192.168.33.33"
  config.winrm.port = 5985
  config.windows.set_work_network = true
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.33"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "provision.bat"    
end
```

I am using selfcreated Win7 enterprise SP1 box

vagrant up hangs on configuring network adapter, debug logs here:

```
DEBUG configure_networks: vm_interface_map: {1=>{:net_connection_id=>"Local Area
Connection", :mac_address=>"08002753776B", :interface_index=>"11", :index=>"7"}
, 2=>{:net_connection_id=>"Local Area Connection 2", :mac_address=>"080027F5E843
", :interface_index=>"14", :index=>"12"}}
INFO winrmshell: Configuring NIC Local Area Connection 2 using static ip 192.16
8.33.33
DEBUG winrmshell: powershell executing:
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection 2" static 192.168.33.33 25
5.255.255.0
```

After "netsh" command execution hangs.

Any workaround of how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

found solution, in my VagrantFile there wrong

config.winrm.host = "192.168.33.33"

this shoult be host IP address, but i used guest IP, thats why while executing netsh command "vagrant up" silently hungs.
Reason is that netsh command resets network interface and vagrant can not get result of netsh comand.

mainly, this parametr should not be set or set to 127.0.0.1